# How can I parse a JSON file with comments in client-side Javascript? (Don't need to preserve comments.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

First, **I know that JSON doesn't support comments.** I'm using them anyway because I need to write little notes to make it easy for people who aren't tech-savvy to edit this file.

I'm using double-slash comments, but I can switch to slash-star if needed.

`"campaignID": "230109-stock-shop", // this is the method I want`

I know the technique of creating extra comment fields like *this*, but it doesn't fit my needs.

`"__comment": "this ISN'T the method I want"`

I'm working entirely in client-side Javascript/jQuery. When I import a file with comments, it - of course - doesn't work.
`$.getJSON('file.json', function (json) {//do things})`

Is it possible to strip out the comments when importing the JSON file somehow? I tried to find a JS library or something that would do that, but everything I found is server-side, and I need everything to run client-side.

I'm also not super great with Javascript, so it's possible I'm missing something obvious.

I really appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: could you load the file as "text", delete your comments, and create your "real" json?

Comment: Instead of including comments in the JSON could you not just have a complementary markdown file (for example) to explain the steps rather than have to programmatically solve this?

Comment: @Andy: I tried to make that work, but unfortunately it's just easier this way. (Easier for my coworkers, not for me. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all the comments before trying to parse it.

You won't be able to use `$.getJSON()`, since that tries to parse the JSON itself. Use `$.get()`, remove the comment and parse it.

```
$.get('file.json', function(commented_json) {
    json = JSON.parse(commented_json.replace(/\/\/.*/g, ''));
    // do things
}, "text");
```

Note that this won't work properly if any of the strings in the JSON contain `//`. That would require using a real JavaScript parser so it can distinguish the context.

Comment: Thanks! You got me most of the way there. I think $.get() sees the file extension and automatically treats it as JSON rather than TXT. I wound up using $.ajax() and specifying the dataType. (I'm posting it as an answer.)

Comment: You can use the third argument to `$.get()` to specify the datatype. I've added that.

Comment: It's not jQuery that does this because of the extension. The server is sending `Content-type: application/json` because of the extension, and jQuery believes that.

Comment: Oh, that's even better. That's working perfectly for me. Thanks for your help!